# Ansible if else constructor in when clause

Tags: ansible

I have playbook which runs PowerShell script:

```
---
- name: Run backup for {{ template_name }}
  hosts: all

  tasks:
  - name: Running backup {{ template_name }}
    win_shell: C:\ansible\backup.ps1 -TemplateName "{{ template_name }}"
    when: inventory_hostname == "server1"
```

Some of templates are on **server1** and other on **server2**.

Is it possible to define `inventory_hostname` based on template name:

Example:

```
If {{ template_name }} == 'linux' then inventory_hostname == server1 else if {{ template_name }} == 'windows' then inventory_hostname == server2
```

I tried this one:

```
when: inventory_hostname = "{% if 'linux' in template_name %} 'server1' {% else %} 'server2' {% endif %}"
```

No errors but PowerShell script is not executed.

Comment: solved it in following way: `tasks:
  - name: Running backup {{ template_name }}
    win_shell: C:\ansible\backup.ps1 -TemplateName "{{ template_name }}"
    when: inventory_hostname == "server1" and (template_name == "linux")
  
  - name: Running backup {{ template_name }}
    win_shell: C:\ansible\backup.ps1 -TemplateName "{{ template_name }}"
    when: inventory_hostname == "server2" and (template_name == "windows")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your self solution comment, you can acheive this in a single task:

```
- name: Running backup {{ template_name }}
  win_shell: C:\ansible\backup.ps1 -TemplateName "{{ template_name }}"
  when: >-
    (inventory_hostname == "server1" and template_name == "linux")
    or
    (inventory_hostname == "server2" and template_name == "windows")
```